# Is it possible to connect Vb6 and PHP?

Tags: php, vb6, connection

I have a vb6 program with mysql as database. My instructor asked me to connect my vb6 to php. The php code only view what is inside in the vb6, e.g. reports. My question is, is this possible? I've googled this one but no concrete ideas occurred. If so, how could I implement this one or what are the steps to achieve this?

I'm confused with this one because I only know php and mysql connection. VB6 to PHP is new thing for me. If this is not possible, maybe i should be using php and mysql. I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: What means 'connect to the vb' ? What kind of tasks should be achieved?

Comment: You have a database, you have php => go for it! :-)

Comment: Can you clarify "The php code only view what is inside in the vb6"

Comment: Can you please explain more on what is needed or what is to be converted? Also provide code when you get the chance. =)

Comment: @DustinDavis: in vb6 I can add, update, delete..In php, i should only view let's say e.g. list of products, reports...

Comment: vb6 could make http requests and call up a php script, but you couldn't have vb6 code invoking php functions. php isn't set up to be a COM object.

Comment: everything clears now. IMPOSSIBLE.Thanks everyone.

Comment: @SoonToBeRevealed I think you just need clarification from your instructor. Based on what you just said about adding/deleting and view only, please see my answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3-WhDmHOE8

Comment: @hakre makes me miss VB6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to throw an answer out there. No, you can't have PHP view what is "inside of VB6". You can't mix VB6 (or any VB) with PHP. But you can have them (the two applications) interact with each other by various methods such as API calls and through datbases.

What I think you mean though, is that you have a VB6 app connecting to and using a MySQL datbase.

Just make a connection to the same MySQL database with PHP and you can have the two systems share the data or "see what is in the VB6".

How to connect to MySQL in PHP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: That's a bad tutorial recommending a deprecated extension. Please replace it with a tutorial on PDO (or MySQLi) so that old practices aren't perpetuated.

Comment: I like how php-mysql-tutorial.com runs .NET... lol.

Comment: @Lusitanian yes, you're right. Was first one I grabbed from google search. I've updated to current documentation.